# PHP loop that stops at every iteration

Tags: php, loops

We have a game we are writing in PHP and we need it to loop through each player and allow them to make their move. The problem we are having is that PHP will loop through the `for` and `while` loop upon page load and not let each player do their turn.

Actually right now it is in an infinite loop since it never evaluates to true because it doesn't let them make their turn. It should stop and let each player `moveHere()`. `activePlayer` enables the game board for each player and once `moveHere` executes properly, it will set `$turnOver` to true. However, the loop never pauses and infinitely loops.

See this code snippet:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$characterCount; $i++)
{
    activatePlayer($i);

    while (!$turnOver){
        moveHere();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which _player_ you are talking about?

Comment: This is not possible with php alone. You are going to need a solution that utilizes javascript, php, and ajax.

Comment: while (!$turnOver) <-- yeurk

Comment: Try to begin a little simpeler, look at some basic tutorials like : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-gamescripts1/index.html?S_TACT=105AGY75

Comment: @Su4p: "yeurk" isn't very helpful.  I don't know what that means.  Please explain more what your comment means.

Comment: It's obvious that php(or any other as I know of) won't handle this kind of charge. You can't make a loop in order to make a pause in the best case you will overcharge your server. In the worst you will crash it. As someone said use Ajax when client turn is over make an ajax call ('localhost/?id=5&act=my_turn_is_over') in order to launch your process. Sure you can do this without ajax but it won't be pleasant from the user POV.

Comment: @user3498593, plenty of answers waiting for you below. The question is rather broad, but they should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

"Pausing" PHP makes no sense. PHP is server-side, you cannot interact with a PHP page at the middle of its execution from the client (the browser).

You should consider reading some [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/) about JavaScript and AJAX (and client/server communication).

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to achieve this in the current format while using PHP alone, you will likely need to use JS, Ajax etc.. PHP is a server based language, and does not have the ability to pause waitign for client side input.

However if you restructure your game to use a more PHP-friendly format, you can achieve the result you are looking for.

For example, when a new 'Game' begins you will initialize an instance of the game and create a record on a table (e.g. Games), then you can store the players (linked from a Players table?), the player who's turn it is (currentTurn?) and the date/time of their last move. Using this info and a query, you can determine who's turn it is and allow the user to make their move.

Answer (score 0):

Consider designing the game from the perspective of the browser instead, using some simple JavaScript.

The game can periodically send an AJAX request to the server to see if it is the current player's turn yet, or to refresh the screen with new data, etc. jQuery is popular for this, but there are several other libraries (MooTools, Prototype, etc).

PHP's role in this then does not need to consider pauses: it just replies to messages. You'll have to re-think your game logic, so that a single turn can be handled outside of the context of the loop you have in mind. This means that the "game state" needs to be saved in some form, probably in a database.

This approach holds true regardless of whether each player is playing the computer, or players are playing against each other. The computer records and reflects the state of the game, and if it is also playing, it has a logic role to perform as well.

This sort of design isn't exactly trivial, even if it's just a simple game - it does require a translation of thinking, from standard loop-based programming to an event-based paradigm. Once you've mastered that, you could switch to using Sockets. These are long-running connections that are faster than AJAX operations, but they require a special server (e.g. Node.js).